# Insufficent permissions when trying to view ratings,reviews of my app using google play console api

Tags: python, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

steps I have done-

1. I have linked my project  in google console Api  by clicking on Link button.
2. Created a service account and generated key along with a json file to have access.
3. Gave permission as **owner** to my mail account so I can retrieve ratings and reviews of my app.

The code I am trying to use to access the rating and reviews in python is as under.

```
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    '<secret from service account>.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'])

service = build('androidpublisher', 'v2', http=credentials.authorize(Http()))

package_name = "<package name>"
reviews_resource = service.reviews()
reviews_page = reviews_resource.list(packageName=package_name, maxResults=100).execute()
```

but I always get the same error on last line.

```
HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/com.policybazaar/reviews?alt=json&maxResults=10 returned "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.">
```

What I am doing wrong ?
unable to guess?
can someone tell how to do it in python?
what step I have missed?

It displays the review resource on printing it but not fetching reviews

Comment: Your code is fine. Does the user have sufficient privileges to access the reviews?

Comment: I have created a service account and give my mail id as an Owner in service account rights thus getting the json file but its driving me crazy not able to access .I created service with an official mail and created a service account giving rights as owner to my other mail id but still getting same error

Comment: Are you able to login to the play console with that user and see the reviews?

Comment: yes I am able to see rating and all reviews and download reports but not here through python